# Built-in template filter for prepending a string to a template in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to prepend a string to a template. I know you can use the `|add` filter to append a string to the end. That's not what I'm trying to do though. I want the string before my template.

For example if my template is `{{ index.salary }}` how would I add a `$` to the beginning?

I know you can make your own filter. I was just curious if they have something built-in for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple tag

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def prepend_dollar(value):
   return "${}".format(value)
```

and in your template you can use it as

```
{% prepend_dollar index.sallary %}
```